# What is the C++ iostream to creating a file with O_EXCL?

Tags: c++17, fstream, iostream, ofstream

I want to create an output file in a threadsafe manner, and only if it does not exist. I want to use the file system for synchronization. With `open()` I would use the flags `O_RWRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL`. Is there a way to do this in C++17 using the `iostream` or `fstream` ?

Comment: No, it is OS-specific stuff.

Comment: C23 and C++23 are considering proper support for this in their respective standard libraries.  POSIX of course defines `fdopen` along with `O_EXCL`, but there’s no portable C++ equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. If you are involved with C++23, it would also be nice to have a standards-based way of doing memory-mapped files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to C++23 there is no way of opening an `ofstream` in exclusive mode.

Workaround: Use [`std::fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) which has this capability since C++17.

Example:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

// Mode "x" to make it fail if it already exists
std::FILE* fp = std::fopen("filename", "wx");

if(fp) {
    // created exclusively

    // work with fp ...

    std::fclose(fp);
}
```

If you really want an `ofstream` you could create a helper function:

```cpp
template<class Stream>
Stream open_exclusively(const std::string& filename) {
    Stream rv;
    
    if(std::FILE* fp = std::fopen(filename.c_str(), "wx"); fp) {
        std::fclose(fp);

        // overwrite the file that was created exclusively:
        rv.open(filename);
    } else {
        // could not create file exclusivly, set the failbit in the stream:
        rv.setstate(Stream::failbit);
    }

    return rv;
}

int main() {
    auto os = open_exclusively<std::ofstream>("filename");

    if(os) {
        std::cout << "file created exclusively\n";
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MMnf7qfP7)

###### Edit:

Even though the above demo is compliant and works on all platforms I've tested it - `wine` (v6.16) can't handle it, so I opened a bug report at [bugs.winehq.org](https://bugs.winehq.org/). You can follow the progress here:

[Standard library call `fopen(..., "wx")` not recognized - causes destruction of data](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51846)

###### Edit 2:

The Wine bugfix [ucrtbase: Add support for x mode in fopen](https://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/commit/51b9f4cd2b7faa04d5bfd50dfe9a4382e0b76fc6) is now included in Wine 6.20 so after upgrading to 6.20 (or later), this will be working as it should in Wine too.

---

From C++23 you can use the `std::ios::noreplace` [`openmode`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode):

```cpp
std::ofstream os("filename", std::ios::noreplace);

if(os) {
    std::cout << "file created exclusively\n";
}
```

Comment: Does this work on WIN32 with mingw?

Comment: @vy32 If it's fully C++17 compliant, yes.

Comment: Great. I'll give it a try. Thanks! I wish that `fclose()` would take a `std::string` but I guess I can't have everything.

Comment: @vy32 :-) True - `fopen`/`fclose` is a C legacy - but it has its uses as in this case.

Comment: Sadly, it is not C++17 compliant. I get this error message: `00fc:err:msvcrt:msvcrt_get_flags incorrect mode flag: x`. (running under Wine)

Comment: @vy32 Oh, that's too bad. Visual Studio (MSVC) does it correctly though.

Comment: Yes, but then I need to compile my .exe on Windows. Ick. @ted-lyngmo

Comment: @vy32 I've made a few tests: If I compile the program with Visual Studio, it works as expected. If I run the same binary in `wine` I get the same error as you do - so wine is incomplete. I tested wine 6.3 and 6.16. I also used `mingw` to compile the program on my linux machine and copied it over to my windows machine. This version failed to open the file. So - I would use a proper compiler and environment since the implementations to emulate and cross compile isn't quite up to speed yet.

Comment: Ted, thank you so much. I should have also checked an actual Windows environment!

Comment: @vy32 You're welcome! I've actually just created a patch in Wine and submitted it to the Wine developers for scrutiny. If it's approved, Wine version 6.19 may include this little bugfix. :-) I tested the same program I compiled with VS2019 with my wine-patch and then it worked just fine.